# xubuntu 12.04 hang on boot of kernel 3.2.0-44-generic

Tags: 12.04, boot, xubuntu

I just updated and got the 3.2.0-44-generic kernel on my desktop Dell T3400. When I rebooted as required it hung in the XUbuntu screen with the moving bar... the bar stopped moving and nothing else happened (I gave up after 5 minutes).

I forced a power cycle and using grub booted 3.2.0-44-generic in recovery mode. The fsck selection reports "Superblock last mount time is in the future"... and "FIXED", the dpkg selection reports no broken packages, and the resume selection runs briefly before hanging. The last things reported are:

```
swapon:/dev/disk/by-uuid/613f8c15-413f-4339-81b4-a3b2b092480f: swapon failed: device or resource busy

swapon terminated with status 255

init ctl: Event failed
```

and DAHDI then prints some stuff with the last thing being "dahdi_transcode:" then it hangs. On one try (but only one of several) after about 15 seconds I got another msg that started with:

```
rcu_sched detected stalls on CPU/taksk: { 1}
```

(**EDIT** Every few tries I get rcu_sched detecting a stall, and most of the time this happens it starts endlessly dumping a bunch of debug info... too fast to make sense of. But once it froze with rcu_sched actually reporting that dahdi_transcode was the actual task that was hung. I dont know how accurate this is since memory may be corrupted by something earlier in the boot process)

Grub memory test was OK. And I can boot the prev kernel (3.2.0-43-generic) OK.

Any thoughts or clues on how to fix this?

---

More info since it looks like a swap partition problem (all from the 3.2.0-43-generic boot):

my /etc/fstab is:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid -o value -s UUID' to print the universally unique identifier
# for a device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name
# devices that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    defaults        0       0
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=c88a26e8-a137-4910-9601-6274caebc1f4 /               ext4    errors=remount -ro,user_xattr 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=613f8c15-413f-4339-81b4-a3b2b092480f none            swap    sw               0       0
/dev/scd0       /media/cdrom0   udf,iso9660 user,noauto,exec,utf8 0       0
```

and "fdisk -l" shows:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 250.0 GB, 250000000000 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 30394 cylinders, total 488281250 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xa42d04a3

Device Boot         Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *          63   476214794   238107366   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       476214795   488279609     6032407+   5  Extended
/dev/sda5       476214858   488279609     6032376   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

where gparted shows sda5 to be within sda2

Answer (score 2):

Since it looked like the dahdi_transcode initialization was hanging the kernel 3.2.0-44-generic boot, I rebooted into kernel 3.2.0-43-generic and removed all dahdi modules using the Ubuntu Software Center, then rebooted into kernel 3.2.0-44-generic. That did it, no more hang during boot. Since I dont use my desktop box for telephony this solution works for me.